# After building apps by py2exe app stopping create file for write

Tags: python, py2exe

**My code for writing text in file:**

```
file = open('folder\text.txt', 'w')
file.write(string.encode('utf-8'))
file.close()
```

**my setup.py file:**

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(
    console=[{"script":"main.py"}],
    options={"py2exe": {"includes":["requests"]}}
)
```

P.S. - windows